# Angular, error declaration of 2 modules,, how solve it?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, build-error, angular-module, ng-build

When I run `ng serve` the application starts.

However, when i run `ng build --prod`, it give me an error on `footerComponent` that says i have declared it in 2 modules. How is it possible?

This is the full error:

> ```
> ERROR in Type FooterComponent in C:/Users/matte/Documents/GitHub
>   /latavolaitaliana/Sito Ufficiale/FE/latavolaitaliana/src/app/footer
>   /footer.component.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules: 
>
> AppModule in C:/Users/matte/Documents/GitHub/latavolaitaliana/Sito Ufficiale
>     /FE/latavolaitaliana/src/app/app.module.ts and FooterModule in 
>     C:/Users/matte/Documents/GitHub/latavolaitaliana/Sito Ufficiale/FE/latavolaitaliana
>     /src/app/footer/footer.module.ts!
> Please consider moving FooterComponent in C:/Users/matte/Documents
>     /GitHub/latavolaitaliana/Sito Ufficiale/FE/latavolaitaliana/src/app/footer
>     /footer.component.ts to a higher module that imports AppModule in
>      C:/Users/matte/Documents/GitHub/latavolaitaliana/Sito Ufficiale/FE/latavolaitaliana
>     /src/app/app.module.ts and FooterModule in C:/Users/matte/Documents/GitHub
>     /latavolaitaliana/Sito Ufficiale/FE/latavolaitaliana/src/app/footer
>     /footer.module.ts.
> You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes FooterComponent
>     in C:/Users/matte/Documents/GitHub/latavolaitaliana/Sito Ufficiale/F/latavolaitaliana
>     /src/app/footer/footer.component.ts then import that NgModule in AppModule in C:/Users/matte
>     /Documents/GitHub/latavolaitaliana/Sito Ufficiale/FE
>     /latavolaitaliana/src/app/app.module.ts and FooterModule in C:/Users/matte
>     /Documents/GitHub/latavolaitaliana/Sito Ufficiale/FE/latavolaitaliana/src/app/footer/footer.module.ts.
> ```

This is footer.module.ts:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FooterComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [FooterComponent],
  imports: [NgbModule,RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
})

export class FooterModule { }
`
```

This is `app.module.ts`:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HomeModule,
    FiverulesModule,
    ContactModule,
    RegisterModule,
    LoginPageModule,
    NewsletterModule,
    FytModule,
    EventModule,
    ZuggModule,
    VdgModule,
    CibourModule,
    MdaModule,
    BlogModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    HttpClientModule,  
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {  
      provide:HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass:BasicAuthHtppInterceptorService, multi:true 
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }`
```

Comment: remove `FooterComponent` from `app.module.ts` in the `declarations` and remove the import at the top.

Comment: and it doesn't work, if i do ng serve or ng build...
ERROR in 'app-footer' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-footer' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-footer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
[ERROR ->]<app-footer *ngIf="showfooter"></app-footer>
")

Comment: The issue is you're declaring the `FooterComponent` in two modules, `app.module.ts` and `footer.module.ts`.  You need to remove it from one of the modules.  Also I'm not sure why you have a router for the `FooterComponent`.

Comment: Here is an stackblitz example how to have `FooterComponent` in its own module. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vmgwaj

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `FooterComponent` in both `footer.module.ts` and `app.module.ts` (see `declarations` property inside `@NgModule` decorator).

Declare component in one module only. If it needs to be shared in two modules, declaring it in an outer module is the recommended solution.

I think, `FooterComponent` needs to be removed from `footer.module.ts`. Since `HeaderComponent` is declared in `app.module.ts` I assume that `FooterComponent` also needs t be declared in`app.module.ts`.

**footer.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FooterComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [NgbModule,RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
})

export class FooterModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HomeModule,
    FiverulesModule,
    ContactModule,
    RegisterModule,
    LoginPageModule,
    NewsletterModule,
    FytModule,
    EventModule,
    ZuggModule,
    VdgModule,
    CibourModule,
    MdaModule,
    BlogModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    HttpClientModule,  
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {  
      provide:HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass:BasicAuthHtppInterceptorService, multi:true 
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert component to a [Tree Shakable module](https://blog.angularindepth.com/emulating-tree-shakable-components-using-single-component-angular-modules-5e3d380364ea) will solve it and if you are using lazy loading it will increase performance as well..

https://blog.angularindepth.com/emulating-tree-shakable-components-using-single-component-angular-modules-5e3d380364ea

Happy Coding ... :)